# How to detect if polygons overlap in leaflet

Tags: polygon, leaflet, overlapping

I am using leaflet draw to create polygons.
My requirement is when a user draws a polygon ,it should not intersect/overlap with existing polygons.
I have used point in polygon leaflet to detect if point falls within the polygon and it is working,
but the problem is i am not able to detect if a line crosses another polygons.In this case points lie outside the existing polygons but overlapping exists.

Below attached image can give a better picture![image: Polygons overlap in this]

Answer (score 7):

You can also probably use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/). Turf is a new js GIS engine developed by the guys at Mapbox.

Here are few examples that may do the job:

- [Turf Intersects](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-intersect)
- [Turf Overlaps](https://github.com/tchannel/turf-overlaps)

Answer (score 2):

In leaflet.draw, you can pass options to individual draw handlers. One of them [`allowIntersection`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#polylineoptions) is a boolean type that "Determines if line segments can cross."

Your options would look something like this (excerpted from the [leaflet.draw example config](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#example-leafletdraw-config)):

```
var options = {
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
            drawError: {
                color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
            },
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#bada55'
            }
        },
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: false
    }
};

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like `allowIntersection` doesn't work with Editable yet.

Comment: `allowIntersection` is a boolean governing an intersection of a polygon with itself, not with other polygons.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also use [Terraformer Core](http://terraformer.io/core/), which is an open-source project done by the folks at ESRI. You would probably do something like this:

```html
var polygon = new Terraformer.Primitive({ 
  "type": "Polygon", 
  "coordinates": [ [ [ -101.46972656250001, 34.125447565116126 ], 
                     [ -100.85449218750001, 33.760882000869195 ], 
                     [ -101.09619140625, 33.19273094190692 ], 
                     [ -102.12890625000001, 33.137551192346145], 
                     [ -102.19482421875, 33.63291573870479 ], 
                     [ -101.46972656250001, 34.125447565116126 ] ] ] }); 
var intersects = polygon.intersects({ 
  "type": "Polygon", 
  "coordinates": [ [ [ -103.32539, 30.58608 ], [ -102.32083, 29.87894 ], [ -103.32539, 30.58608 ] ] ] });
// intersects is a bool.
```